# moving hadoop installation into /usr/local/hadoop

Tags: hadoop

I want to move the Hadoop installation to the /usr/local/hadoop directory, but i time it says

```
~/hadoop-2.6.0$ sudo mv * /usr/local/hadoop
mv: target ‘/usr/local/hadoop’ is not a directory
```

Comment: small thing, might not be a solution but might be too, you want to move the dir `~/hadoop` to `/usr/local/` not `/usr/local/hadoop` as the `hadoop` folder, does not exist, you want to move it, so `~/hadoop-2.6.0$ sudo mv * /usr/local/` will move the `hadoop` folder and its contents, creating `/usr/local/hadoop` in the prosses, let me know if this helps you

Comment: If you want the path `/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop` then `sudo mkdir /usr/local/hadoop` and `~/hadoop-2.6.0$ sudo mv * /usr/local/hadoop` should now work

Comment: This sounds like [an X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you actually trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

You want to move the Hadoop installation to the `/usr/local/hadoop` directory. So, we should create the directory first:

```
hduser@Soumitra-PC:~$ sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/hadoop
[sudo] password for hduser:
hduser is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported.
```

This can be resolved by logging in as a sudoer, and then adding hduser to the sudo group:

```
hduser@Soumitra-PC:~/hadoop-2.6.0$ su soumitra
Password:    # I enter soumitra's password
soumitra@Soumitra-PC:/home/hduser$ sudo adduser hduser sudo
[sudo] password for soumitra:
Adding user `hduser' to group `sudo' ...
Adding user hduser to group sudo
Done.
```

Now, the hduser can use `sudo` to gain root privilege, we can move the Hadoop installation to the `/usr/local/hadoop` directory without any problem:

```
soumitra@Soumitra-PC:/home/hduser$ sudo su hduser
hduser@Soumitra-PC:~$ sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/hadoop
[sudo] password for hduser:
```

Please note, before doing the next step, don’t forget to do a `cd`    into the directory `hadoop-2.6.0`.

```
hduser@Soumitra-PC:~/hadoop-2.6.0$ sudo mv * /usr/local/hadoop
```

[Detailed Step-by-Step Installation of Hadoop on Ubuntu, with detailed screenshots and Explanation](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0YcHWv8cfAjdzAxbjlReUNLWUU/view)

This document has been created by me after installing several versions of Hadoop on several versions of Ubuntu. So, most of the common problems/errors/queries that a person faces while installing Hadoop on Ubuntu has been discussed in the above document.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you don't have a folder `hadoop` in `/usr/local`

so follow the steps:

```
sudo mkdir/usr/local/hadoop
sudo mv hadoop-2.6 /usr/local/hadoop
cd /usr/local/hadoop
sudo ln -s hadoop-2.6 hadoop
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't copy contents of the folder. Copy complete folder.

Follow the steps.

```
sudo rm /usr/local/hadoop
cd ..
sudo mv hadoop-2.6.0 /usr/local
```

Comment: First step is not needed as nothing was created. Second step assumes they are still in the directory which is unlikely 2 years later, and third step doesn't give them exactly what they asked for (although it's an XY problem in my view)